# pythonic way to add items to list while reading input from user

Tags: algorithm, python-3.x, list

input :
 3 2
 0 5
-3 2
 7 10
 1 6

first row contains the number of segments , number of points 
the next ith rows based on number of segments,
the last lines contain the points .

```
 myinput = sys.stdin.read()
 data = list(map(int, myinput.split()))
 n = data[0] # number of segments
 m = data[1] # number of points
 starts = data[2:2 * n + 2:2] # lefts of segments
 ends   = data[3:2 * n + 2:2] # rights of segments
 points = data[2 * n + 2:] # points
```

this would provide :

starts(old) --> [0,-3,7]

ends(old) --> [5,2,10]

i want it to be like

starts(new) --> [[0,'l'],[-3,'l'],[7,'l']]

ends(new)   --> [[5,'r'],[2,'r'],[10,'r']]

this is part of sorting algorithm , i know that i can do it in a separt function that iterats and appends 'l'/'r' but my goal is to reduce time here.

algorithm:

1 make list containing the point and corresponding 'l' , 'r' , 'p' ----- O(n)

2 sort the list (Merge) ------ O(nLogn)

3 scan for the points within segments------- O(n)

so i'm trying to avoid the 1st step :) thanks!

Comment: `starts = zip(data[2:2 * n + 2:2], 'l'*n)` - is what you wanted????

Comment: i did as u said , and when i printed starts it gave me this : <zip object at 0x7fc0ac2d5948>

Comment: `starts = [zip(data[2:2 * n + 2:2], 'l'*n)]` - this will materialize a generator

Comment: or try next: `starts = [[x,'l'] for x in data[2:2 * n + 2:2]]`

Comment: I _think_ `n,m = data[:2]` should work (I might be off by one, but I think that slicing is exclusive for the end)

Comment: the `starts = [[x,'l'] for x in data[2:2 * n + 2:2]]` worked , but i think this is iteration also , i'd like more fast way of passing 'l','r','p' while capturing the user input . your solution reduced the time by 0.4 sec , the grader took 4.4 sec instead of 4.8 sec . but thanks :D